# Find methods which return null and are not marked with [CanBeNull]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to search for methods which returns null and are not marked with [CanBeNull]? I have Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper plugin with it. Using search function for return null; is bit too time consuming.

Comment: In my opinion to see whether a function returns `null` is only possible with a runtime analysis.

Comment: I am now meaning methods which have the "return null;" at the end.

Comment: Do a full-text search through all files.

Comment: That would give me all of the methods but I would need to limit the search to methods which does not have that marking [CanBeNull]